# IP Address Control in wxWidgets

Tags: mfc, wxwidgets

In MFC there is a control to enter IP(v4) address called CIPAddressCtrl.  Does wxWidgets have an equivalent?  Or, do I need to create a custom control?

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged as MFC?

Comment: The CIPAddressCtrl is an MFC control, therefore in the hope of getting an appropriate answer to see if there is an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

No, wxWidgets doesn't wrap the native Windows IP address control because nothing like this exists under the other platforms and it seems a bit pointless to provide something for Windows only.

The best you can do is indeed use a custom control, which could be as simple as just a plain `wxTextCtrl` with an appropriate validator.

Comment: So, wxWidgets provides no control to wrap the entry of an IP address?  That I would need to create one (or see if one has already been created -- codeproject.com)